# Angular 4 - How to invoke Custom Validator on blur?

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, directive, blur

I have a template driven form where I need to make a http call to check if a user's email address is available.

I need to make this call on blur of the email textbox, I'm trying to do it via a custom validator directive but unfortunately the validation gets invoked on every keypress (this seems to be the default behavior which I do not want in this scenario).

```
@Directive({
selector: '[app-email-check][ngModel]',
providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailCheckValidator),
        multi: true
    }
]
```

})

```
export class EmailCheckValidator implements Validator, OnInit {
validator: ValidatorFn;

constructor(private _emailHelper: EmailHelperService) {

}

ngOnInit() {

}


validate(control: FormControl) {
    return this._emailHelper.isEmailAvailable(control.value)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return { emailCheckValidator: { valid: false } };
            }
        });
}
```

}

I see that in Angular 5 they have fixed this by allowing you to specify the update type:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

**Edit - Added HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddr"
 [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddress" app-email-check  #emailAddress="ngModel" required />
```

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you also show the template?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post to include it.

Comment: your validator is different from https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms.

Comment: Yeah its slightly different but both still result in the same issue, i only want the validation to fire on blur of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating an abstract class that disables async validators on focus of the control.  On blur of the control the validators get re-enabled and triggered.

```
export abstract class AbstractCustomValidator implements OnChanges {

    private asyncValidators: any;
    private wasChanged: any;


    @ContentChild(NgControl) formControl: NgControl;

    constructor() {
    }

    // On focus of control, clear all async validators so they do not fire on keypress
    @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
    onFocus($event) {
        this.wasChanged = false;
        this.asyncValidators = this.formControl.control.asyncValidator;
        this.formControl.control.clearAsyncValidators();
    }

    @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
    onKeyup($event) {
        this.wasChanged = true;
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.wasChanged = true;
    }

    // On blur of control, re-enable all async validators so they fire 
    @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
    onBlur($event) {
        this.formControl.control.setAsyncValidators(this.asyncValidators);

        if (this.wasChanged) {
            this.formControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
    }
}
```